# Android Studio is not recognizing runtime permission code

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-permissions

I'm trying to implement runtime permissions (targeting SDK 24), but Android Studio doesn't seem to recognize all the code.

Everything is fine until I get to ".READ_CONTACTS" or ".CAMERA." Also, "requestPermissions." turns red as well. I've tried importing various things, such as "android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat" to no avail.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            yeahReadContacts();
        }else{
            requestPermissions. //This and "READ_CONTACTS" are red.
        }}
```

Also, I'm calling this from a custom dialog class, but I didn't think that should be a problem, as these are supposed to be "run-time" permissions, right??

[Example of runtime permissions code turning red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koZnf.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried clean an build already?

Comment: Enzokie - thanks, but clean didn't help.

Comment: If any of the answer didn't work, I can have a quick TeamViewer on that part since this issue is not reproducible.

Comment: Enzokie - Thanks - I don't know what a TeamViewer is, but I'm open to help!

Comment: Okay, I emailed you. Thx!

Comment: Thanks so much to @Enzokie for helping via TeamViewer.

Comment: We got one problem fixed - somehow my code had created a stupid Manifest.java file somewhere that was conflicting with opening the library version of Manifest, so we drilled down in the project hierarchy, found the offending file, and renamed it to ManifestNot.java. Finally, the .READ_CONTACTS is working, but I still have to get requestPermissions() to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out both problems, with the help of @Enzokie.

The .READ_CONTACTS part of Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS because I had somehow created a file called Manifest.java, and needed to rename it to something like ManifestNot.java, because it was conflicting with the Manifest library feature.

Secondly, the library function requestPermissions was red because I was calling it from a Dialog, and needed to prefix it with mActivity, which was an Activity object I created and initialized in the constructor method of my dialog:

```
Activity mActivity; //Declared

//The constructor
public AddEntityDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mActivity = (Activity) context;
}
```

Of course I needed to define a couple arguments that requestPermissions requires as follows, but then I was able to write the code without it becoming red.

```
String[] perms = {"android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"};
int permsRequestCode = 100; //This can be any number
```

Then the final line is no longer red:

```
mActivity.requestPermissions(perms, permsRequestCode);
```

Here's a good chunk of the code for better context:

```
public void readContacts(){

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        yeahReadContacts();
    }else{
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            mActivity.requestPermissions(perms, permsRequestCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of try this example.
It works for me perfectly..

https://learnpainless.com/android/marshmallows/runtime-permission-example-good-practice-real-example

Comment: Pawneshwer Gupta - Thanks, but the first line in your example, right after setting the onClickListener on btn, is "getPackageManager()," and when I type it into my example, it shows up red like Android Studio is not recognizing it.

Comment: If its not recognized then write Activity.getPackageManager()

Comment: Pawneshwer Gupta - Thanks again, but that also isn't recognized. "Activity" is recognized; but ".getPackageManager()" after it is not.

Comment: And that getPackageManager() is to check if camera hardware is available on device or not

Comment: If its still not recognized then use getActivity(). getPackageManager()

Comment: I this you are doing this inside fragment. Then you have to ise getActivity()

Comment: getActivity() turns red. I'm inside a custom dialog class which extends Dialog and implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener

Comment: Ohh then u need to take reference to Context. Do u have context in this class??

Comment: Bingo. I had to declare Activity mActivity, then cast mActivity = (Activity) context within the constructor of the Dialog, then use mActivity.requestPermissions(...)

Comment: great... :)
if my answer really helped then mark as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same error. This is how it gets solved:

Just change:

```
Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
```

to

```
amdroid.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
```